# does Samsung Transfix 2.3.4 support Android USB Accessory

Tags: android, accessory

I am trying to develop a Android app that uses Open Accessory (usb accessory host mode).  I have a Cricket Samsung Transfix phone. It has version 2.3.4 android.  When I load my app is get an error

"Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY"
   E/PackageManager(147): Package com.st.android.adkping requires unavailable shared library com.android.future.usb.accessory; failing!

Does Samsung Transfix support Open Accessory?
Can I load usb.jar( inside the apk)?

It loads in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

read this out

http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.4.html

If Samsung Transfix  supports 2.3.4  then it supports USB

Comment: Not necessarily.  From your link, "The Open Accessory Library is optional on any given device. Device manufacturers may choose whether to include the Open Accessory Library in their products or exclude it."  However, the non-Google solution used by IOIO of enabling ADB and emulating a development machine should probably work.